# Adding Runs to Paragraphs

Tags: ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I'm trying to convert xml formatted with  tags to a DOCX file. I'm not generating a new document, but inserting text in a template document.

```
<p id="_fab91699-6d85-4ce5-b0b5-a17197520a7f">This document is amongst a series of International Standards dealing with the conversion of systems of writing produced by Technical Committee ISO/TC 46, <em>Information and documentation</em>, WG 3 <em>Conversion of written languages</em>.</p>
```

I collected the text fragments in an array, then tried to process them with code like this:

```
foreach (var bkmkStart in wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.RootElement.Descendants<BookmarkStart>())
{
        if (bkmkStart.Name == "ForewordText")
        {
                forewordbkmkParent = bkmkStart.Parent;
                for (var y = 0; y <= ForewordArray.Length / (double)2 - 1; y++)
                {
                        if (ForewordArray[0, y] == "Normal")
                        {
                                if (y < ForewordArray.Length / (double)2 - 1)
                                {
                                        if (ForewordArray[0, y + 1] == "Normal")
                                        {
                                                forewordbkmkParent.InsertBeforeSelf(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text(ForewordArray[1, y]))));
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                                fPara = forewordbkmkParent.InsertBeforeSelf(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text(ForewordArray[1, y]))));
                                        }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                        fPara.InsertAfter(new Run(new Text(ForewordArray[1, y])), fPara.GetFirstChild<Run>());
                                }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                NewRun = forewordbkmkParent.InsertBeforeSelf(new Run());
                                NewRunProps = new RunProperties();
                                NewRunProps.AppendChild<Italic>(new Italic());
                                NewRun.AppendChild<RunProperties>(NewRunProps);
                                NewRun.AppendChild(new Text(ForewordArray[1, y]));
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

but I end up with malformed XML because the runs are inserted after the paragraphs instead of inside them:

```
<w:p>
    <w:r>
        <w:t>This document is amongst a series of International Standards dealing with the conversion of systems of writing produced by Technical Committee ISO/TC 46, </w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
<w:r>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:i />
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>Information and documentation</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:p>
    <w:r>
        <w:t>, WG 3 </w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
        <w:t>.</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
<w:r>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:i />
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>Conversion of written languages</w:t>
</w:r>
```

Doing this the right way, using the SDK, would be best. As an alternative, I was able to create a string with all the correct XML and text using regexes, but I can't find a WordprocessingDocument method to turn that into an XML fragment that I can insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this kind of problem is to perform a pure functional transformation, as shown in the following code example.

The code example uses the sample XML element `<p>` given in the question (see `Xml` constant below). It transforms it into a corresponding Open XML `w:p` element, i.e., a `Paragraph` instance in terms of the strongly-typed classes provided by the Open XML SDK. The expected outer XML of that `w:p` or `Paragraph` is defined by the `OuterXml` constant.

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
using Xunit;

namespace CodeSnippets.Tests.OpenXml.Wordprocessing
{
    public class XmlTransformationTests
    {
        private const string Xml =
            @"<p id=""_fab91699-6d85-4ce5-b0b5-a17197520a7f"">" +
            @"This document is amongst a series of International Standards dealing with the conversion of systems of writing produced by Technical Committee ISO/TC 46, " +
            @"<em>Information and documentation</em>" +
            @", WG 3 " +
            @"<em>Conversion of written languages</em>" +
            @"." +
            @"</p>";

        private const string OuterXml =
            @"<w:p xmlns:w=""http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"">" +
            @"<w:r><w:t xml:space=""preserve"">This document is amongst a series of International Standards dealing with the conversion of systems of writing produced by Technical Committee ISO/TC 46, </w:t></w:r>" +
            @"<w:r><w:rPr><w:i /></w:rPr><w:t>Information and documentation</w:t></w:r>" +
            @"<w:r><w:t xml:space=""preserve"">, WG 3 </w:t></w:r>" +
            @"<w:r><w:rPr><w:i /></w:rPr><w:t>Conversion of written languages</w:t></w:r>" +
            @"<w:r><w:t>.</w:t></w:r>" +
            @"</w:p>";

        [Fact]
        public void CanTransformXmlToOpenXml()
        {
            // Arrange, creating an XElement based on the given XML.
            var xmlParagraph = XElement.Parse(Xml);

            // Act, transforming the XML into Open XML.
            var paragraph = (Paragraph) TransformElementToOpenXml(xmlParagraph);

            // Assert, demonstrating that we have indeed created an Open XML Paragraph instance.
            Assert.Equal(OuterXml, paragraph.OuterXml);
        }

        private static OpenXmlElement TransformElementToOpenXml(XElement element)
        {
            return element.Name.LocalName switch
            {
                "p" => new Paragraph(element.Nodes().Select(TransformNodeToOpenXml)),
                "em" => new Run(new RunProperties(new Italic()), CreateText(element.Value)),
                "b" => new Run(new RunProperties(new Bold()), CreateText(element.Value)),
                _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException()
            };
        }

        private static OpenXmlElement TransformNodeToOpenXml(XNode node)
        {
            return node switch
            {
                XElement element => TransformElementToOpenXml(element),
                XText text => new Run(CreateText(text.Value)),
                _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException()
            };
        }

        private static Text CreateText(string text)
        {
            return new Text(text)
            {
                Space = text.Length > 0 && (char.IsWhiteSpace(text[0]) || char.IsWhiteSpace(text[^1]))
                    ? new EnumValue<SpaceProcessingModeValues>(SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve)
                    : null
            };
        }
    }
}
```

The above sample deals with `<p>` (paragraph), `<em>` (emphasis / italic), and `<b>` (bold) elements. Adding further formatting elements (e.g., underlining) is easy.

Note that the sample code makes the simplifying assumption that `<em>`, `<b>`, and potentially further formatting elements are not nested. Adding the capability to nest those elements would make the sample code a little more complicated (but it's obviously possible).

Comment: Thanks, I'm learning something new. I notice that TransformElementToOpenXml calls TransformNodeToOpenXml and TransformNodeToOpenXml calls TransformElementToOpenXml. How does that avoid creating an infinite loop?

Comment: @JohnKorchok, if you look at the unit-tested code, you will see that it recursively traverses the hierarchical XML node tree, but no recursion goes back to a previously visited node. For example, if you pass a `<p>` element to `TransformElementToOpenXml`, it creates a `Paragraph` to which it adds the result of transforming each child node of your `<p>` element. If the child node is an `<em>` element, for example, `TransformElementToOpenXml` will be called with that `<em>` element, which will yield a `Run` and stop the recursion right there.